# Do while as often as data is in database but max. 5 times

Tags: php, mysql

I want a while that fills up a table with database information but just as often as rows exist but max. 5 times if there are more than 5 rows it should echo a show more button
This one outputs everything that is in the table

```
while($row = $statement->fetch())  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href="http://example.com/'.$row['id'].'">example.com/'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

and this one outputs it 5 times but even if there is nothing

```
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++; &&$row = $statement->fetch())  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href="http://example.com/'.$row['id'].'">example.com/'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
I hav
```

e tried something with mysqli_num_rows but it didn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Amend your query and add `LIMIT 5` at the end of it. This will only return a MAX of 5 rows, less if there are less rows that satisfy your where clause. This will also stop you returning 1000 rows and only using 5 of them, thus reducing wasted network traffic.

Then use your `while` loop as that will consume all the result set, and there will never be more than 5 rows to consume.

```
while($row = $statement->fetch())  {
```

Answer to your comment:

I did say put the `LIMIT 5` at the end of your query !

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM link 
                            WHERE userid= $uid 
                            AND only = 'true'
                            LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM link LIMIT 5 WHERE `userid`= $uid AND `only` = 'true'"); doesn't output anything now

Comment: @Naruto Thanks for tryin, I think with only 1 rep OP has to wait a while before they are allowed to accept

Comment: Trying to get this closed or trying to help you? ^^